# Old MSDN Magazine link not working

Tags: discussion, broken-link

This is not a programming question, but more an issue with MSDN Magazine old links.

Many answers & comments on stackoverflow have msdn magazine links. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316743/are-there-any-design-patterns-used-in-the-net-framework) voted answer for the question. MSDN Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx. This link is dead and redirects to MSDN magazine home page. This is one example, there are lot many dead links like this.

Currently, I believe links older than 2008 have been archived and are available as CHM files only.

So, My question

Is there a way to get the MSDN magazine issue Year and month from a Link ?
Is their a online copy of archive hosted by any other 3rd party maintaining these links ?
Note: I have read the article mentioned in the link few year back. I am not just looking for information of above link, but for all the dead links which we get in stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like archive.org has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20080922064321/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx

Comment: Thanks Shog9, web.archive.org works.