# Links in the question

Tags: discussion, questions, external-links

I recently tried to ask the question about different toolkit here: [Is URL recognition possible in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290548/is-url-recognition-possible-in-qt).

However I was pointing out that the SO is frowned upon using links in the question, especially this type.

Could someone please clarify - is it true? Is it really better to use plain text even if you compare different toolkits, platforms, APIs, etc?

Comment: Nothing wrong with links.  But assuming people will follow it and understand what it's saying isn't going to go well.  You need to explain what data you're trying to extract, not just assume people will understand.

Comment: Question must be self-contained. Here you use the word this with a link and assume one read an msdn article before reading the rest of the question. If the link die, your question is nonsense.

Comment: Ask yourself "if the link goes down, what is left of my post"....

Comment: It boils down to "I have a problem with this, how do I do it in QT?", with a this hypoteticaly ranging from self Driving care to election prediction. I will recommend [ask]. As it state proofreading, selfcontained, and pretend the other one doesnt know what you are talking about.

Comment: @yivi, except that it is more broad.

Comment: The answer is exactly the same, and it even says so explicitely. I admit I remembered it only because I wrote that answer.

Comment: @Patrice, except I never saw MSDN link just die. It is an official documentation from self-respected company.

Comment: @Igor so? it can be down for a couple of minutes/hours/days or, if something REALLY bad happens, simply goes out/changes link. "it never happened" isn't a good answer to "what if it happens one day?"

Comment: @Igor, "except I never saw MSDN link just die. It is an official documentation from self-respected company." Well they do. A lot of them are already dead.. There is even question on meta about how to fix them..[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310115/old-msdn-magazine-link-not-working), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363610/microsoft-connect-died-and-breaks-lots-of-links) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286256/should-we-fix-all-msdn-links)

Comment: Using "this" is about the worst link-text that could have been used - it doesn't contain any information without following the link. I'm sure the feature you linked to has a name that could be used instead....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that "links are discouraged", but rather that your question needs to stand on its own as a good question even if no links are followed.  Links should be used to cite sources, or to provide tangential or additional information, and not be a necessary part of getting the information to answer a question.  If someone can't answer your question without following the link, that's a problem.